# Is GROUP BY needed for aggregation function?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation

Question:

> Given the CITY and COUNTRY tables, query the names of all the
>   continents (COUNTRY.Continent) and their respective average city
>   populations (CITY.Population) rounded down to the nearest integer.
>
> Note: CITY.CountryCode and COUNTRY.Code are matching key columns. Do
>   not include continents without cities in your output.

My solution:

```
SELECT COUNTRY.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.POPULATION)) FROM COUNTRY INNER JOIN CITY ON COUNTRY.CODE=CITY.COUNTRYCODE
```

But this doesn't seem to work until I add a GROUP BY statement
Updated solution:

```
SELECT COUNTRY.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.POPULATION)) FROM COUNTRY INNER JOIN CITY ON COUNTRY.CODE=CITY.COUNTRYCODE GROUP BY COUNTRY.CONTINENT
```

Why is that so? Why doesn't the average population value of the new INNER JOIN table be displayed? 
I understand that this will give me the wrong answer i.e., it will display the same average population value for each continent. But my doubt is why is it not working when I don't add the GROUP BY statement.

The error thrown:

> ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 1: In aggregated query without GROUP BY,
>   expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column
>   'run_y53padyvlle.COUNTRY.continent'; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: This behavior is explained in the MySQL documentation also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: it's because this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the `AVG()`.  You can do:

```
SELECT FLOOR(AVG(ci.POPULATION))
FROM COUNTRY c INNER JOIN
     CITY ci
     ON c.CODE = ci.COUNTRYCODE;
```

This returns one row which is the overall average population for all cities in the database.

The problem is when you do:

```
SELECT c.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(ci.POPULATION)) 
. . .
```

The `CONTINENT` part is unaggregated.  The SQL engine needs to know what to do with it.  Putting the key in the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY c.CONTINENT
```

says that you want one row in the result set for each value in `CONTINENT`.